# Makefile by ocaml and cpp extension

Tags: c++, makefile

I have large number of `.ml` and `.cpp` files in a same directory which are totally independent of each other. Is there any way I can compile them with `Makefile` without using external bash / shell scripts?

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++14 -Wno-unused-variable
CCML=ocamlc
SHELL := '/bin/bash'
.SUFFIXES = .cpp .ml

cpp_objs:=$(wildcard *.cpp)
ml_objs:=$(wildcard *.ml)
cpp_targets:=$(cpp_objs:.cpp= )
ml_targets:=$(ml_objs:.ml= )

targets:=$(cpp_targets) $(ml_targets)

.PHONY:all
all: $(targets) 
# all: $(cpp_targets) 
.ml: 
    $(CCML) -o $@ $<
.cpp:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

What's wrong with this `Makefile` that only recognises my `.cpp` files :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `[ML-FILES]', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Update: All the `*.ml` and `*.cpp` files has unique name in the directory.

Thanks.

Comment: What `make` invocation corresponds with this error? What is `ML-FILES`?

Comment: Say I have `a.ml` in the directory, it yells `make: *** No rule to make target a', needed by all'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) you are supposed to configure `.SUFFIXES` like a target, not like a variable:

```
.SUFFIXES: .cpp .ml
```

However, the better approach is to use pattern rules so you can drop the use of `.SUFFIXES` entirely.

```
%: %.ml
    $(CCML) -o $@ $<
```